# Is print() atomic in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I know the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) only switches among threads between bytecode instructions, so that most operations on lists and dictionaries are atomic etc.

But does `print()` correspond to a single bytecode instruction in Python3, so that it can be considered an atomic operation?

Bonus: What happens, if one thread modifies (e.g. insert) into a list that another thread is for-looping?

http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I think your bonus question would be more suited for a separate question.

Comment: @StephenRauch - I have a threaded program. I want to know if I should use a mutex.

Answer (score 4):

Look for yourself:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(lambda: print("foo"))
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo')
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

So there's just `CALL_FUNCTION`, nothing more... Unless `print` itself is complex?

```
>>> dis.dis(print)
TypeError: don't know how to disassemble builtin_function_or_method objects
```

So, `print` is a built-in, written in C, and calling it is just the one bytecode (if you disregard placing arguments onto stack to prepare for the call).

EDIT: But see the results of deeper digging by Anthony Sottile!

Comment: Thank you - so I don’t need to place print() in mutex between threads?

Comment: AFAIK, you shouldn't have to, no.

Comment: For `print` to have a chance to be atomic it must do one `write` syscall. When you pass more than one argument to `print`, does C implementation of `print` concatenate the strings before a write, or does it call `fwrite` call per argument? It does the latter to avoid concatenating, which would require memory allocation, which could fail and crash the process and that would be unreasonable. For multi-argument atomic `print` Python must invoke `writev` syscall, but that would require bypassing C library buffering. `print` in Python uses C library stdio and, hence, cannot guarantee atomicity.

Answer (score 3):

(*note* this answer assumes cpython implementation details.  GIL is a cpython implementation detail as well so I think this is ok)

`print` is implemented in C -- while it is true that it is only a single bytecode as @Amadan mentions, there is potential for GIL release

Here's (important bits of) the source for [`print()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/461d225b195eec5269f317323b41115516144c41/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1895-L1915):

```
    for (i = 0; i < nargs; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            if (sep == NULL)
                err = PyFile_WriteString(" ", file);
            else
                err = PyFile_WriteObject(sep, file,
                                         Py_PRINT_RAW);
            if (err)
                return NULL;
        }
        err = PyFile_WriteObject(args[i], file, Py_PRINT_RAW);
        if (err)
            return NULL;
    }

    if (end == NULL)
        err = PyFile_WriteString("\n", file);
    else
        err = PyFile_WriteObject(end, file, Py_PRINT_RAW);
    if (err)
        return NULL;
```

The important thing to note here is that there are *multiple* calls to `PyFile_Write*`.  Each of those ~usually invoke some sort of `write()` method.  And where do the write methods end up in? Usually [`_Py_write`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Python/fileutils.c#L1485-L1506):

The important bits from the docstring:

> Release the GIL to call write(). The caller must hold the GIL.

With this information:

- `print` in cpython is a single byte code
- a call to `print` can lead to multiple calls to a `write()` function
- In almost all cases, `write` may release the GIL.

If if it's easier to convince yourself of this, consider a custom file object:

```
>>> class MyFile(object):
...     def write(self, obj):
...         sys.stdout.write(f'called! {obj!r}\n')
...
>>> import sys
>>> print('hi', file=MyFile())
called! 'hi'
called! '\n'
```

Comment: It may also be worth considering that all the arguments to `print` need to be converted to strings, usually by having `str` called on them. If their `__str__` method is implemented in Python, they may release the GIL in between bytecodes within `__str__`. Printing only builtin types *might* avoid that trap, but I wouldn't want to count on it.